# LinkMovementMethod with Accessibility

Tags: android, hyperlink, textview, accessibility

I have a textView in my app , which has a link to a URL.

Below is the code :

**textView.setText(Html.fromHtml("<\a href=\"https://example.com\">Sign up now."));
enroll.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());**

When I turn on TalkBack for accessibility, this does not seem to work. However, I found out that it works well if I put a longer text , for example "Sign Up now bla bla bla".

What could be the issue ?

Comment: What do you mean by "does not seem to work"? What is the expected behavior and what actually happens?

Comment: Means, nothing happens when you click on it, the expected link doesnt open up.

Comment: Double-tap performs a click action by simulating a normal DOWN/UP touch event in the center of the accessibility-focused view. If the link happens to sit at the center of the view, you would get a click action as expected; however, there is no special handling for inline links or ClickableSpans. For this reason, the preferred way to access inline URLSpans is through the [local context menu](https://support.google.com/accessibility/android/answer/6007066?hl=en).

Comment: When i removed the dot at the end of html string , it worked.